# Depending on Data on Firebase - build buttons including Images and Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm quite new to programming and was looking quite a while now for a solution - but as I am not sure what exactly I am looking for, I decided to ask you.

Depending on the Data on Firebase I was looking to build a button including text and an image.

So for example I have a Database including:

```
User
Max (with the fields: University, Age, City)
Lena (with the fields: University, Age, City)
```

Is it possible to build a button with this Data but only if the Users are in the Database? So as there are 2 users - build 2 buttons including all the text (University, Age, City), if there would be 3 users - build 3 buttons.

Edit: Using Android Studio

Comment: Use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` or you can build you own `RecyclerViewAdapter` for this.

Comment: What platform are you programming for?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using recycler view and implementing onClick for recycler view.
This would take a lot of code:

1. Create xml for each item of recycler view

recycler_view_item.xml

2. Add recycler view to xml of current activity

3.Create a class MyUser.java like below:

```
public class MyUser {

private String University, City, Age;

public User(){}

public User(String University, String City) {
    this.University = University;
    this.City = City;
    this.Age = Age;

}

public String getUniversity() { return University;}

public void setUniversity(String University) {
    this.University = University;
}

public String getCity() {
    return City;
}

public void setCity(String City) {
    this.City = City;
}

public String getAge() {
    return Age;
}

public void setAge(String Age) {
    this.Age = Age;
}
```

}

4. Create adapter and view holder class

5.get user details from database in current activity :

```
private List<Book> userList;
userList = new ArrayList<>();

mRef = database.getReference().child("users");
    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Iterable<DataSnapshot> bookData = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            for(DataSnapshot d : bookData){

                MyUser myUser = d.getValue(User.class);
                userList.add(myUser);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Initialise the adapter with context and the userList

```
mAdapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), userList);
```

I have left out a lot of things like the adapter and view holder.
comment if u are stuck

Comment: refer to this github project if u are new to recycler view https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals/tree/master/RecyclerView

Comment: Thanks sammy! I will try to understand and implement it :)

Comment: Hey Sammy, I just wanted to inform you, that thanks to your help I was able to implement it :)